# Looking for reference to solve a problem (representation theory, I think)

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules, representation-theory

This question appeared on an algebra qualifying exam:

> Let $R$ be the group algebra $\mathbf{C}[S_3]$.  How many nonisomorphic, irreducible, left modules does $R$ have and why?

Would I be able to find how to answer this in Serre's representation theory book?  If so, is it in part 2 or part 3?

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried looking at the section titled "number of irreducible representations"?  It's section 2.5, at least in the version I am looking at.

Comment: I am not too comfortable in this setting.  So "irreducible module" and "irreducible representation" are the same in this problem?  It appears group algebras don't come up until part 2

Comment: Yes, a representation of a finite group is the same thing as a module of its group algebra, and the notion of irreducible (also sometimes referred to as simple) is the same for either notion.

Comment: I'm vaguely beginning to recall that there is a correspondence between modules and representations, in the group algebra setting.  I think the answer I need is to understand that correspondence from part II and then apply the results from part I (as you suggest)